# How to build node js applciation?

Tags: node.js

it is generic question.
I know that if I have java project I can run `mvn clean install` and it will build the project and the artifacts will be jar or war in target folder
if U have node.js application How I can build it ? I know that I have package.json that could run with npm install and the artifices are node modules but I guess there is a way to build the result of the node application . what is the type of the result ?

Comment: You don't really "build" a regular node.js application.  There is no compile step.  There is no separate executable.  Whatever your main entry Javascript file is, you would just run it with `node main.js` and everything else will be loaded from there as your Javascript files load other modules.  There are transpilers and there are packagers that can do special things, but none of that is needed for a regular node.js app.

Comment: but if I write something wrong in the code.How i can check it for example like mvn

Comment: Javascript is an interpreted language (like PHP, Python, Perl, etc...), not like Java.  You will likely get a run-time error when you run your app if you write something wrong in the code.  Of course, there are all sorts of tools that will check things for you before you run your code (such as linters), but Javascript does not work like Java in that regard.  If you want a "typed" and "checked" language, then you can use TypeScript which is "compiled" into Javascript that node.js can run and the compile step for TypeScript will check your syntax for you.

Comment: You cannot generally rely on compilation to catch all the problems in your code. To make sure your code works as intended, you need testing.

Comment: @user1365697 To catch syntax errors in your code all you have to do is run it - there is no compile step. Run it and it will error out if there are errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to build node js application?

You don't really "build" a regular node.js application. There is no compile step. There is no separate executable. Whatever your main entry Javascript file is, you would just run it with `node main.js` and everything else will be loaded from there as your Javascript files load other modules.  The Javascript interpreter will compile your JS files on the fly as they are encountered.  If there is a syntax error when the file is loaded, it will throw an exception at that time.

For the simplest possible hello world application, you'd just put this into a text file named `main.js`:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

And, then type this at the command line:

```
node main.js
```

And, you would see your output in the console.  No compile step.  No build step.

There are transpilers and there are packagers that can do special things, but none of that is needed for a regular node.js app.

> but if I write something wrong in the code.How i can check it for example like mvn

Javascript is an interpreted language (like PHP, Python, Perl, etc...), not like Java. You will likely get a run-time error when you run your app if you write something wrong in the code. Of course, there are all sorts of tools that will check things for you before you run your code (such as linters), but Javascript does not work like Java in that regard.

If you want a "typed" and "checked" language, then you can use TypeScript which is "compiled" into Javascript that node.js can run and the compile step for TypeScript will check your syntax for you, enforce data typing, etc...